# Overwrite drupal calendar theming

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, calendar

I am trying to theme a calendar view, is there a way to override the theming path with a module instead of overwriting the template files?

I want to create a module that overrides the theming functions so I can include the template files in my module instead of the calendar module.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override views template in a module, see the "Theming your views in your module" in the [Using default views in your module](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views) page of Views' Advanced Help. Since Calendar is a views plugin, I think the basic behaviors of Views templating applies. If declaring your own themeable output in your [`hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme/6) doesn't work for a Calendar view, you may need to use [`hook_theme_registry_alter(&$items)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that in a module, at least not in a clean way.

Drupal have functionality (*modules*) and presentation (*themes*) separated. It makes good sense to divide the two.

- Cleaner more maintainable code.
- Functionality needs is common among different sites.
- Presentation and functionality is often done by different people (developers and themers)

So I wouldn't be surprised if you *could* do something like this in a module. But you would be working against Drupal, have a hard time doing it, and with no good reason.

If you want to create reusable styles, template overrides etc, use the sub theme system instead.

Comment: yes, that is the problem, calendar doesn't have hooks so I have to override it's theming. I also want to change some functionality but I can't extend the module for as far as I can see

Comment: In some cases, one needs to build a functionality on top of an existing modules and requires some default presentation elements to be added to an existing template. In these cases, templates are is welcome in a module. For instance, one module can provide a custom custom ''dashboard'' page build with Views that need some modification to the default Views' templates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're looking to do here is rewrite how the `calendar` module functions, in a way that completely replaces normal calendar behavior before the theme layer has a chance to meddle with it.

In these (hopefully rare) cases, the best thing to do is create your own fork of `calendar` as a new module, with the existing `calendar` code as a starting point. Modifying the module code directly will be much easier than trying to hack Drupal's basic functionality/display interactions.

I normally wouldn't recommend this, but it seems appropriate in your case.

Be sure to send any improvements back to the calendar devs so that we all can benefit :)

Comment: Maybe I can write a hook in the calendar module, and check if a module exercises the hook and then cancel default behaviour. then upload it as a patch?

Comment: Even better, I'd say :) But, you'll want to implement the hook a little differently than you described, since hooks aren't usually meant to replace eachother or override normal behaviors. Rather than having hooks cancel the default behavior, you should have the hook *replace* the default behavior, then move the original behavior into an instance of the module calling it's own hook.

Comment: user_user is a good example of how other modules have implemented overridable default behaviors using hooks.